# Ruby on rhodes with ajax

Tags: ruby, ajax, rhodes

I am trying to build a dynamic dropdown in ruby on rhodes.There are basically two dropdowns on my screen and i am using ajax to get the values of the second dropdown from the database depending on the value selected in the first dropdown..I am a newbie to ruby and do not know the syntax on how to use ajax in ruby on rhodes..

JavaScript Code I am using...

```
<script>
$.post("/app/Settings/dropdown",
  {
    value:a
  },
  function(data){
     alert(data);
});
</script>
```

-----Partial Controller  Code

```
def dropdown
  @a = @params['value']
  puts @a;
  if @a.eql?"Auto"
    mystring="auto1|auto2|"
  else
    mystring="personal1|personal2|"
  end
end
```

I can get any parameter sent via ajax call to controller..My Question is how to send back the data from controller to function in that ajax call so that i can use that information to create a dynamic dropdown..??

Answer (score 0):

You can send back JSON using `render` in your controller:

```
def dropdown
  value = params[:value]
  if value == "Auto"
    @options = ["auto1", "auto2"]
  else
    @options = ["personal1", "personal2"]
  end
  render :json => @options
end
```

Then with JavaScript you update your dropdown using this data you receive.

Comment: In 5.4 it doesn't work anymore. This work fine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208807/ruby-on-rhodes-using-ajax-call.